# How can I see who I have already invited to Google+?

Tags: google-plus

I've sent some invitations to Google+. Some users signed up, some didn't. I want to avoid sending repeat invitations to those who didn't sign up, but I lost track of who these people are.

Is there any way to see my "sent invitations", specifically for those who have *not* signed up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created extra circles to keep track of this:

- to be invited
- invited but not accepted yet
- don't invite (people who've told me they don't want G+)
- deprecated profiles (for people who've signed up twice, this circle hold their old account so that G+ won't keep on suggesting that I add them.)

Answer (score 2):

If you added them to a circle when you sent the invite you can see if they've signed up.

If their name is still an e-mail address rather than a link to a profile then they haven't signed up.

You can also check to see if they've added you to one of their circles.

Comment: If they've signed up with a different mail address then my circled contact will remain email-only, but I usually catch those duplicates. My concern is about those who haven't signed up, whom I don't want to spam with repeated invites.

Comment: @torbengb - I was sent an invite to a different e-mail than I signed up with, but Google+ seems to have been clever enough to sort that out.